# Non-ASCII characters in python 2 shebang

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

As [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) says, Python 2 (specifically 2.7 in my case) requires a magic comment line to specify a file encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Without that it is not possible to include non-ASCII characters in the file. A notorious error would be raised:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '[…]' in file […] on line […], but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
```

However if the non-ASCII character is in the shebang interpreter path, the magic comment does not work:

```
#!/Users/naïve/project/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'Hello.'
```

This happens for example if you create a `virtualenv` in a folder with a non-ASCII path: Many scripts with a shebang that breaks the script are created.

The only workaround I could come up with is to symlink the folder into some ASCII-only path. Then it is possible to change the shebang path to the ASCII one. Or in the case of `virtualenv` to initialize it from the symlinked path.

However this cannot be done if the non-ASCII part of the path is the user’s home path and the user does not have administration access. So I’d like to ask: Is there any other workaround for this situation, hopefully more clean? E.g. some default file encoding setting or environment variable that would Python use if it does’t find a magic comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file as `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8`, you don't need an encoding-cookie at all. That is, use a [unicode byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when saving the file.

In python you can use `utf-8-sig` as an encoding-parameter. In VIM you can use `:set bomb` to explicitly save the file with a BOM.

Comment: Interesting. When I save the file with BOM, the system (macOS) completely ignores the shebang. It runs it as a `bash` script instead of the Python specified.